# How can I attach dynamic objects to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom

I am using D3.js to create a chart as described in this simplified example

```
class MyClass {
   // logic goes here
   // constructor() and other functions defined here.
   doSomething() {
       console.log('something.');
   }
}

function createChart(chartID, data) {
    // creating the SVG and appending it to the body
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                     .attr('width',400)
                     .attr('height',400)
                     .attr('id',chartID);

   // instantiating an instance of MyClass to be attached to the SVG
   var anObject = new MyClass();
   svg.myObject = anObject;   // this has no effect


   // code to actually build the chart + math to be done on passed data

   // finally, attach a click event to the svg so that data can be manipulated later on
   svg.on('click',function(){
        var object = d3.select(this).myObject;   //this does not work
        object.doSomething();                   // so this also doesn't work
   });
}

createChart('test1',[1,2,3,4]);   // triggering the createChart() function
```

I am assuming that the variable `svg` is treated like any JSON object, so, I thought I could attach any object to it.

Apparently, that is not the case. How can I go about attaching an object to an HTML DOM element, so that I may access the object later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svg` variable is a d3 selection object containing DOM elements.

You can set the `datum()` of the svg and later retrieve it

```
function createChart(chartID, data) {
    // creating the SVG and appending it to the body
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                     .attr('width',400)
                     .attr('height',400)
                     .attr('id',chartID);

   // instantiating an instance of MyClass to be attached to the SVG
   var anObject = new MyClass();
   svg.datum(anObject);


   // code to actually build the chart + math to be done on passed data

   // finally, attach a click event to the svg so that data can be manipulated later on
   svg.on('click',function(){
        var object = d3.select(this).datum();
        object.doSomething();
   });
}
```

Or use the fact that `this` in `click` handler is a DOM element

```
function createChart(chartID, data) {
    // creating the SVG and appending it to the body
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                     .attr('width',400)
                     .attr('height',400)
                     .attr('id',chartID);

   // instantiating an instance of MyClass to be attached to the SVG
   var anObject = new MyClass();
   svg.node().myObject = anObject;


   // code to actually build the chart + math to be done on passed data

   // finally, attach a click event to the svg so that data can be manipulated later on
   svg.on('click',function(){
        var object = this.myObject;
        object.doSomething();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the already [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596114/5768908), this is a good use for *D3 local variables*.

According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local-variables):

> D3 locals allow you to define local state independent of data.

So, you can set the local...

```
var local = d3.local();

local.set(svg.node(), myObject)
```

... and easily get it:

```
local.get(svg.node())
```

That way you don't need to bind unnecessary data (that is, data not related to the visualisation) to the DOM elements.

Here is a demo:

```js
var local = d3.local();

class MyClass {
  doSomething() {
    console.log('something.');
  }
}

function createChart(chartID, data) {
  var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 200)
    .attr('height', 200)
    .attr('id', chartID);

  var anObject = new MyClass();
  local.set(svg.node(), anObject)

  svg.on('click', function() {
    local.get(this).doSomething()
  });
}

createChart('test1', [1, 2, 3, 4]);
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```